# CSS - Filling rest of Webpage with Black

Tags: css, background-image

I've a webpage with a background image that needs to be kept sharp and in focus.

The problem is that to achieve that it obviously has to have a set size every time.

I need a way of filling in the remaining space (which will vary from screen size to screen size) with black.

The easiest way to see what i'm talking about is if you go to the webpage: (no self promotion meant)
 http://hopeish.com

Particularly if you are using chrome and firefox - as safari is okay and IE isn't being affected in the same way

Any ideas how I can do this??

Comment: I'm not sure what you want but `background-color: #000;` set on body will make rest of the page black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
background: url(image.jpg) #000 no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
background:#000 url(image.jpg) bottom right no-repeat;
```

this way your picture will be at the bottom right and the rest will be filled with black.

Answer (score 0):

You currently have:

```
body {
  background: url(image.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*background-attachment:fixed;*/
}
```

Add `background-color: black;` to have a full black background.

```
body {
  background-color: black;
  background: url(image.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*background-attachment:fixed;*/
}
```

Or use the shorthand background property variant seen in the other answers.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background

Answer (score 0):

Achievable with simple CSS.

```
body {
    background: url('http://hopeish.com/image.jpg') no-repeat top right black;
}
```

**[Here's a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Gppks/)**